# Phase space/Differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

You have two solutions of an differential equation with the same eigenvalues.
How can you see, that the phase space are lines:

$ y_1=c_1e^{\lambda t} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$

$ y_2=c_2e^{\lambda t} \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Exactly what solutions do you have? There are two rather different possibilities when you have a repeated eigenvalue.

Comment: The eigenvalues are greater than 0.

Comment: That’s not the most interesting condition. A defective eigenvalue generates a very different phase portrait than if both its algebraic and geometric multiplicities are 2.

Comment: Sorry for that. The  algebraic and geometric multiplicities are 2.

Comment: $\dot y_1=\lambda_1 y_1$ and $\dot y_2=\lambda_2  y_2$ are lines, no?